# Syntaxis Problem when creating a trigger in Mysqlite

Tags: trigger, sqlite

how u doing?,

I have a problem that I don't understand, when I create a Trigger in Mysqlite, check it:

```
 c.execute("""CREATE TRIGGER ahoraSI BEFORE INSERT ON Productos
             FOR EACH ROW
              BEGIN
               INSERT INTO Registro_cambios VALUES (' Numero de pedido '   ||NEW.id|| '  Nombre de producto '  ||NEW.nombre_producto|| '  fecha de adquisicion: '  ||NEW.fecha_adquisicion|| '   cliente asociado  ' ||NEW.fecha_adquisicion||);
              END """)
```

The thing is that when I add a simple string like "new product" to "Registro_cambios " it works but when I try to do it like this with the actual informacion of the products using ||NEW."something"|| doesn't work and always Bash return me that is a syntaxis problem:

> "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error" if someone can
> help me, Thanks

Comment: Please add table definition , some data example and expected result, so we can understand what are you trying to achieve. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: `... NEW.fecha_adquisicion||);` - remove last `||`

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to split long queries to multi-line:

```
 c.execute("""CREATE TRIGGER ahoraSI BEFORE INSERT ON Productos
             FOR EACH ROW
              BEGIN
               INSERT INTO Registro_cambios
               VALUES (' Numero de pedido '   ||
                       NEW.id||
                       '  Nombre de producto '  ||
                       NEW.nombre_producto||
                       '  fecha de adquisicion: '  ||
                       NEW.fecha_adquisicion||
                       '   cliente asociado  ' ||
                       NEW.fecha_adquisicion||
                      );
              END """)
```

This way, you immediately see that after adding field `NEW.fecha_adquisicion` you are trying to add something else. But instead there is just an unexpected `)`. So you have an error.